# Transponer resultado de un query de SQL server de columnas a filas sin usar Pivot

Tags: sql-server

Hola necesito ayuda para transponer el resultado de un query no puedo usar pivot porque en el servidor esta restringido esta función

es una consulta simple mi consulta actual es

```
select
SUM(nLlamadasRecibidas),
SUM(nLlamadasSalida) 

FROM dbo.Tbl_ACDGRALREAL

WHERE dFecha = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),121)
AND cCentro IN ('MARRON') 
AND cSkillNumero IN ('4001')
group by dFecha
```

El resultado naturalmente se muestra así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero debo poder verlo así lo ideal es que el 503 se muestre en la fila 1 y el 45 en la fila 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los campos que consulto son estos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sería útil que nos mostraras los campos de las tablas que consultas, sería más fácil conociéndolas, pues es un poco difícil de imaginar solamente con la query

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola Eduardo ya edite la pregunta poniendo los campos

Answer (score 1):

Dado que no has plasmado un ejemplo mínimo con datos, voy a sustituir tú consulta por una variable de tabla, aunque la solución es aplicable a la misma, utilizando tablas de expresión común y encerrando el origen de la misma como conjunto source.

Te planteo dos posibles soluciones.

**Cross join**

```
Declare @table table (col1 varchar(100), col2 varchar(100), col3 varchar(100), col4 varchar(100), col5 varchar(100), col6 varchar(100))
Insert into @table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
values
('Reincidencia 16:30 hrs',
'Llam Rec: 3,378',
'Llam Alba: 320',
'TM: 00:13:57',
'Alba: 9%',
'Staff: 52'
),
('Caso 2_ Reincidencia 16:30 hrs',
'Llam Rec: 1,111',
'Llam Alba: 1111',
'TM: 00:11:11',
'Alba: 1%1',
'Staff: 111'
);

With source as (
        Select * from @table 
    ),data
     As (Select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select null)) as row
                From @table)
    Select case when n=1 then col1
                when n=2 then col2
                when n=3 then col3
                when n=4 then col4
                when n=5 then col5
                when n=6 then col6 end as result
    from data
    Cross apply
    (Select * from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6))T(n)) n;
```

***Nota***: He puesto dos filas, la que tienes y otra porque en el origen de tú consulta no se observa que el resultado pueda devolver una sola fila.

En el conjunto `source`, tomamos los datos. Aquí sería donde se reemplazaría por tú consulta.

En el conjunto `data`, numeramos las filas para poder ordenar los registros.

Y en la salida de data, hacemos un producto cartesiano de lo que teníamos, con el [Constructor con valores de tabla Values](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/05/arrays-en-sql-server-constructor-con-valores-de-tabla/), para las 6 columnas.

[image: Resultado]

Ahora tenemos cada fila repetida 6 veces.

La solución consiste en obtener con un case cada uno de las columnas en función de el valor de n.

**Resultado final:**

[image: Resultado]

Es también aplicable con utilizando en vez de `cross join`, [cross apply](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/06/27/operador-apply/)

**Union all**

```
Declare @table table (col1 varchar(100), col2 varchar(100), col3 varchar(100), col4 varchar(100), col5 varchar(100), col6 varchar(100))
Insert into @table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
values
('Reincidencia 16:30 hrs',
'Llam Rec: 3,378',
'Llam Alba: 320',
'TM: 00:13:57',
'Alba: 9%',
'Staff: 52'
),
('Reincidencia 16:30 hrs2',
'Llam Rec: 3,3782',
'Llam Alba: 3202',
'TM: 00:13:572',
'Alba: 9%2',
'Staff: 522'
);

With source as (
        Select * from @table 
    ),data
     As (Select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select null)) as row
                From @table)
    , trasponer
     As (Select t.col1
              , 0 As sortOrder
              , row
                From data As t
         Union All
         Select t.col2
              , 1
              , row
                From data As t
         Union All
         Select t.col3
              , 2
              , row
                From data As t
         Union All
         Select t.col4
              , 3
              , row
                From data As t
         Union All
         Select t.col5
              , 4
              , row
                From data As t
         Union
         Select t.col6
              , 5
              , row
                From data As t)
     Select t.col1
            From trasponer t
        order by t.row, t.sortOrder;
```

Es muy similar a la solución anterior.

En el conjunto source tenemos los datos. Donde puedes reemplazar tú consulta por `Select * from @table`

En `data`, numeramos los registros que tenga `source`

En `trasponer`, leemos mediante union all *6 veces* `data`, añadiendo un número para poder identificar ordenadamente la salida.

El resultado es leer el conjunto trasponer y ordenarlo, por el registro, y por el número añadido.

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Ya puse en practica tu ejemplo uno y super funciono, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la solución puede ser mucho más simple usando `APPLY` y el constructor de tablas `VALUES`. Dejo un ejemplo que podrías completar con todas las columnas. Por cierto, esto no se haría con PIVOT sino con UNPIVOT.

```
SELECT  orden,
        grupo,
        SUM(valor) 
FROM dbo.Tbl_ACDGRALREAL
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( 1, 'Llamadas Recibidas', nLlamadasRecibidas),
                   ( 2, 'Llamadas Salida', nLlamadasSalida),
                   ( 3, 'Llamadas Atendidas', nLlamadasAtendidas),
                   ( 4, 'Llamadas Abandonadas', nLlamadasAbandonadas)) u( orden, grupo, valor)
WHERE dFecha = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),121)
AND cCentro IN ('MARRON') 
AND cSkillNumero IN ('4001')
GROUP BY orden, grupo
ORDER BY orden;
```